# Moving files in powershell into different location

Tags: powershell

It's supposed to move all files in $source into $destination. But something is not working here..

```
$source = Get-ChildItem 'E:\files' -Recurse
$destination = Get-ChildItem "C:\destination" -Recurse
foreach($file in $source)
{
Move-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination
}
```

Comment: Destination is a path (of a folder) why are you using `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: `Move-Item -Path 'E:\files\*' -Destination 'C:\destination'` should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you are supposed to do it:

```
$source = Get-ChildItem -Path X:\Directory -Recurse
$destination = "Y:\Directory"
foreach ($item in $source) { Move-Item -Path $item -Destination $destination }
```

A one-liner would be:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path X:\Directory -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination Y:\Destination
```

Your first mistake was the declaration of the destination variable: It should be just `$destination = "C:\Destination"`; and, second, you created an "index" named `$file` but you did not use it inside the `foreach`, which should be `Move-Item -Path $file -Destination $destination`.